# Send a queryset from Django views to JQuery

Tags: python, jquery, django

I want to send a JsonResponse of a queryset from Django views to JQuery but I am not getting any data from the JQuery side.

This is my views file `add_field_views.py` :

from django.http import  JsonResponse

```
def drop_down_requests(request):
    text = request.POST['text']
    print("---->", text)
    from captiq.financing_settings.models import ChoiceGroup
    response = ChoiceGroup.objects.get(slug="Ja/Nein")
    output = JsonResponse(response,safe=False)
    print("output -", output)
    return output
```

this is where I declared the URL in `urls.py` inorder for the Jquery to GET the data from the views :

```
urlpatterns = [
   
    path('my-ajax-test/', add_field_views.drop_down_requests, name='ajax-test-view'),
]
```

project `urls.py`:

```
frontend_urls = []
for module_name, module_data in FRONTEND_MODULES.items():
    frontend_urls.append(re_path(
        module_data['url'],
        XFrameSameOriginView.as_view(template_name=module_data['view']),
        name=module_name))

urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(
    path('admin/', admin_site.urls),
    path('admin/log_viewer/', include(
        ('log_viewer.urls', 'log-viewer'), namespace='log-viewer')),
    path('admin/docs/', include('docs.urls')),
    path('_nested_admin/', include('nested_admin.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include(
        ('accounts.urls', 'accounts'), namespace='accounts')),
    path('api-auth/',
         include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),

)

api_v1_patterns = [
    path('financing/', include(
        ('financing.urls', 'financing'), namespace='financing')),
    path('financing-settings/', include(
        ('financing_settings.urls', 'financing_settings'),
        namespace='financing_settings')),
    path('partners/', include(
        ('partners.urls', 'partners'), namespace='partners')),
    path('accounts/', include(
        ('accounts.urls', 'accounts'), namespace='accounts')),
    path('customers/', include(
        ('customers.urls', 'customers'), namespace='customers')),
]

urlpatterns += [
    path('api/v1/', include((api_v1_patterns, 'api'), namespace='api')),
    path('', RedirectView.as_view(url='loan-application/auth')),
    path('notifications/', include(
        'notifications.urls', namespace='notifications')),
] + frontend_urls

if settings.ENABLE_ROSETTA:
    urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
        path('admin/rosetta/', include('rosetta.urls')),
    )

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(
        settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

then is my JQuery which is waiting for the queryset data or JSON data :

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    (function ($) {
        "use strict";
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#id_depending_field").change(function (event) {
                console.log("am here man");
                const valueSelected = this.value;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'my-ajax-test/',
                    data: {
                        csrfmiddlewaretoken:
                        document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')[0].value,
                        text: valueSelected
                    },
                    success: function callback(response) {
                        console.log("____________", response)
                    }
                });
            })

        });
    })(django.jQuery);
});
```

With the code above am not able to get JSON data in JQuery, Instead I get a weird HTML output below :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/notifications.css">

.
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Please show what your output shows in your view and in AJAX's `success` callback

Comment: @GProst, I updated my question, for the output I get weird HTML content

Comment: What is the page URL that you send AJAX request from?

Comment: The page url is this `http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/admin/financing_settings/field/add/?edit=1`, I thought I was supposed to use the one in `urls.py` ? @GProst

Comment: show your full urls.py, you might have problems with urlconfig

Comment: Its already there @AndreyMaslov in the Qn

Comment: Show `urls.py` in project folder and in app folder

Comment: @Lutaaya Huzaifah Idris no, you showed only 1 line of it, but there could be problem if you have similar rules for other pages and django find other page for you

Comment: @AndreyMaslov, I have updated my question

Answer (score 1):

when you use relative path it is easy to lead your urls to wrong place. at your page your ajax will call for `/en/admin/financing_settings/field/add/my-ajax-test/`.

you can save exact url on your html page with `data-*` attribute.
In your example add `data-ajax_url` attribute to your `#id_depending_field` (or any other element)

`data-ajax_url="{% url "api:financing_settings:ajax-test-view" %}"` - url must be like this as i understand your routing

and then in your ajax code instead of `url: 'my-ajax-test/',` use `url: $(#id_depending_field).data('ajax_url')`

this will always give you exact url from any page where you load your `.js` file. And later if you decide to refactor your project and change url path it will keep all changes for you without changing `html` or `js` code

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, am still not getting the `data-*` attribute , how can I add it to the dropdown (id_depending_field), I was making the `onchange` function to get a value selected from each. Then secondly where do I put this line : `data-ajax_url="{% url "api:financing_settings:ajax-test-view" %}"` ?

Comment: Thirdly, do I need to put a URL like this `url:url: $(#id_depending_field).data('ajax_url')` ? kindly try to edit my code in your answer, for more clarification, am still new to Jquery

Comment: add you `html` template to your question and i will show you how can you do that

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute URL when sending AJAX request:

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: '/my-ajax-test/',
  data: {
  ...
})
```

Apparently, you were sending it to `/en/admin/financing_settings/field/add/my-ajax-test/` cause it was relative

Comment: Am getting :    - >  jquery.js:10099 POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/my-ajax-test/ 404 (Not Found)